# Front-Camera: What does each icon do?

Tags: settings, camera, lg-g4, front-camera

I cannot find information on the front camera settings on the LG G4.

In particular, I would like to know what the icon on the leftmost side does (hand holding phone and arrow). See screenshot below for reference.

Any help understanding this icon would be greatly appreciated in addition to the functions of the other icons. A diagram would be most helpful. For some reason one for the front camera settings was not included in the user guides that I came across when I searched online.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: LG G4 User Guide maybe it have detailed instructions about camera settings : www.lg.com/ae/mobile-phones/LG_G4_manual.pdf